# Thread Pool compile error

Tags: c++, boost-asio, threadpool, boost-thread

When i try to compile my thread pool with one task i got following error :

> error: 'void ThreadPool::enqueue(F) [with F =
>   CConnection::handle()::]', declared using local type
>   'CConnection::handle()::', is used but never defined
>   [-fpermissive]

Here is thread pool declaration :

```
class ThreadPool {
public:
    ThreadPool(size_t);
    template<class F>
    void enqueue(F f);
    ~ThreadPool();
private:
    // need to keep track of threads so we can join them
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<boost::thread> > workers;

    // the io_service we are wrapping
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work working;
    friend class Worker;
};
```

Here is function, what want to use thread pool to test :

```
void CConnection::handle()
{
     ThreadPool pool(4);
     pool.enqueue([1]
    {
        std::cout << "hello " << 1 << std::endl;
        boost::this_thread::sleep(
            boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000)
        );
        std::cout << "world " << 1 << std::endl;
    });
     char * databuffer;
     databuffer = new char[16];
     for(int i = 0;i<16;i++)
     {
      databuffer[i] = 0x00;
     }
     databuffer[0] = 16;
     databuffer[4] = 1;
     databuffer[8] = 1;
     databuffer[12] = 1;
     asynchronousSend(databuffer, 16);

}
```

And here is enqueue definition :

```
template<class F>
void ThreadPool::enqueue(F f)
{
    service.post(f);
}
```

Can some one found what I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the definition of enqueue in the ThreadPool.h header?  This is required for template methods

Comment: @Kacper Ok, that's what I meant.  It needs to be in the header